# Why does the account_id not equal the private_key when creating a new account?

Tags: accounts

I use the following demo to create a new account on testnet:

```
import requests

from stellar_sdk import Keypair, Server

# Generate random keypair
keypair = Keypair.random()

print("Public Key: " + keypair.public_key)
print("Secret Seed: " + keypair.secret)

# Call the Api to create a test account via Friendbot
response = requests.get(f"https://friendbot.stellar.org?addr={keypair.public_key}")
if response.status_code == 200:
    print(f"SUCCESS! You have a new account :)\n{response.text}")
else:
    print(f"ERROR! Response: \n{response.text}")
```

According to the [official documentation](https://developers.stellar.org/docs/glossary/accounts/) I'd have expected that the account_id equals the public key used to create the account, but it [does not](https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GDRLPSAU6VWKQZKXH3RPBHBQ6MSA5QC45EXNO6KLAROIK7I7Y5H6J5UZ).

What do I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea where you got the idea that the *secret* should be shown as the account_id.
The account_id is the *public key* that is cryptographically derived from the secret.

Also it wouldn't make sense if the secret would be shown publicly somewhere as the secret is like a password that gives you access to the account.
So revealing it, would mean that *anyone* can make payments (and other operations) from the account.

That's also why you always need to keep secrets somehwere save, hence the name "secret".

Comment: Typo in my post, I of course mean the public key.

Comment: @Jonas but the account_id matches the public key ... or you'd need to provide an example where you're able to show that the public key doesn't match the account_id ... or maybe post a public key and the horizon URL to it's account to show that they don't match ...